# I would like to understand e notation and how to round it in python

Tags: python

print("%10.3e"%(356.08977)).

### output: 3.561e+02

Can anyone explain me output of this. I really don't understand the logic in it.

Answer (score 1):

For starters `e` means that you choose [scientific notation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/scientific.html). For example:

```
>>> 8e-2
0.08         # 8 * 10**-2
```

Now about the `10.3` you are practically saying that you want 3 decimals. As a result:

```
>>>print("%10.4e"%(356.08977))
3.5609e+02
```

So the output means `3.561 * 10^2`

Comment: Just for completion, here is the link to the formatting specs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec